# I would like to trigger a count after every peak in a generated 1D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have some code where after every loop an image is analyzed and the average pixel intensity value from the image is appended to a 1D array (`result_array`). So this 1D array is growing by one value every loop. The array when graphed with time shows a frequency and I would like to start a counter to count the frames in between each 'peak' so that I can use that value to calculate frequency per minute.

For example: when I print (`result_array`) I get this after 28 loops:

```
[255.   3.   1.   0.  16.  26.   3.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
   2.  11.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   4.  12.   1.   0.]
```

By eye the peaks are 255, 26, 11, and 12 and each number in between is a frame that I would like to be counted and turned into a value for a frequency equation. Then refreshed and repeated after each peak. How do I detect this position and then initiate the count? I have very little programming knowledge so the more basic knowledge the better.

Here is my loop:

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)
    cv2.imshow('Masked', fgmask)

    average = (np.average(fgmask))
    average_int = int(average)

    result_array = np.append(result_array, average_int)
    print(result_array)
```

Hope it was clear, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_peaks_cwt` from `scipy.signal` to get all peaks positions, and then 
calculate diffs

```
>>> from scipy import signal
>>> peaks_pos = signal.find_peaks_cwt(result_array, range(1, 5))
>>> peaks_pos 
array([ 1,  5, 15, 25])
>>>
>>> peaks_pos[1:] - peaks_pos[:-1]
array([ 4, 10, 10])
```

Comment: Thank you, your guys examples cleared it up very nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on @c2huc2hu's suggestion in the comments.

```
from spicy.signal import find_peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(result_array)
```

Peaks is now

```
array([ 5, 15, 25])
```

which are the indices of the peaks in your array. That itself should serve as your counter –- there are five elements before the first peak, then ten (15-5), then ten (25-15).

You can verify this output with

```py
result_array[peaks]
```

which will yield

```
array([26., 11., 12.])
```

the local maxima of your array.